# How to merge segments in solr manually?

Tags: solr, lucene

in  solr admin ui,i saw that one of my solr cores has 165 segments.this condition will slow queries.To make it faster,I wonder how to merge all of the solr segments into single?
thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify MergePolicy in **solrconfig.xml**, so that Solr will merge segments by himself.

What you need to do roughly - is to add something like this (of course updating with your needs)

```
<mergeFactor>10</mergeFactor> <!-- or any numbers you like-->
<mergeScheduler class="org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler"/>
```

It will do it automatically and will do it by some schedule. I guess it's preferred way.

For more info on configuration - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/IndexConfig+in+SolrConfig#IndexConfiginSolrConfig-MergingIndexSegments

If you need simple way - just click on **optimize** button in Solr Admin UI for this core

[image: solr admin ui]

Comment: Just keep in mind that you need as much free space as the index is large. The optimize will create a copy of your index, optimize it and then swap the optimized version to production.

Comment: that's to say ,I set the mergefactor to 200 and the index has 165 segments now ,and then if I want to merge them to single,what should I do is just to set the mergefactor to 1 and solr will do this itself.

Comment: that's to say ,I set the mergefactor to 200 and the index has 165 segments now , then if I want to merge them to single,what should I do is just to set the mergefactor to 1 and solr will do this itself. Is my understanding right? I once thought that the merging only occurs when commit.

Comment: When you adjust the mergefactor, solr will every now and then do an optimize in case that there are too many segments. Setting this value to 1 for production use is not a very good idea from my experience. This would be wise if you have an archived index where no commits happen. I would aim for a value between 7-20 depending on how often you perform index operations.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a command which you can manually use to force segments to merge -

```
/update?optimize=true&waitSearcher=false&maxSegments=1
```